# How to change tmp directory without using the drupal interface

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've moved my live website drupal to windows localhost(xammp), but I'm getting lots of "The file could not be created" errors. If I log in to the site as an administrator, it fails to return any more pages at all. I can view it with errors if I don't log in.

Is there a way to change the temporary file location from an `ini` file or via `mysql` database rather than logging in through the interface.

`NOTE: without login in admin panel and : admin/config/media/file-system`

Thanks.

Comment: temporary file or temporary dir?

Comment: Please don't cross post. I noticed just now that you asked the same question on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50765/how-to-change-tmp-directory-without-using-the-drupal-interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `variable` table exists a row with name = 'file_temporary_path'. Change it's value, using this SQL:

```
UPDATE 
    variable 
SET 
    variable.value = 's:5:"\\xammp\\temp";' 
WHERE
    variable.name='file_temporary_path';
```

Comment: Thanks, I found This But I don't Know How to UPDATE This. My Temporary path is: `/xammp/tmp`

Comment: Use phpMyAdmin - it's the simplest way. Or create a script, that will connect to the database and update.

Comment: Use phpMyAdmin and SQL Command i test this line: `UPDATE variable SET file_temporary_path = 's:5:"\xammp\temp";';` But I see This Error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'file_temporary_path' in 'field list'`.

Comment: Added the SQL code into the answer. Works fine on my machine. Try it and let me know.

Comment: +1,You Update Code Worked Now perfectly. Thanks. god bless you.

Comment: Great :). plz, mark my answer as solving the question.

Comment: 5 in `'s:5:"\\xammp\\temp";'` is the string length. The string is longer than 5 characters.

Comment: Can use drush to do it: drush vset file_temporary_path /tmp

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to change the content of the variable database table, remember that every value in that value is serialized through [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php); `serialize("\\xammp\\temp")` returns `'s:11:"\xammp\temp";'`.

If you installed [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush), you can use [drush vset](http://drush.ws/#variable-set) to set a Drupal variable.